# Scrolling parallax background based on player

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm creating a game where I have a camera following a player. I've found a lot of examples of backgrounds that auto move but I'm looking for an example of backgrounds that move left or right based on the players position. Not just a single background but at least 2 for a parallax effect. I've not found a good example of how to do this and am hoping someone can point me to some examples. Thanks so much!

```
// MARK: Update Function
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

    if ( self.isPaused == false) {
        if walking {

            thePlayer.update()
            playerCamera?.position = thePlayer.position
            controllerBase.position = CGPoint(x: thePlayer.position.x - 700, y: thePlayer.position.y - 450)

            moveImage()
        }
    }
}

func moveImage() {

    if playerSpeed > 0 {    // Walking Right
        city.position.x -= playerSpeed / 2
    }   
}
```

Comment: Whether you go east or west, the direction to which the earth rotates doesn't change.

Comment: This is easy, just run an SKAction whenever the user presses the left or right movement buttons. (Move backgrounds to the right when the user presses the left one, then move the backgrounds left when the user presses the right one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to leave the nearest background in place and move the far background at half the speed of the player. Feel free to provide the code to have a better explanation. :]

Comment: Of course! I knew I was making this harder than it had to me, thanks for the suggestion. I already was capturing player speed so I had it handy. I quickly made this update before work and it was perfect. I'll figure out the syntax for walking left after I get home. I added my test code above.

Comment: Glad you found that useful. I see you have a controllerBase at a fixed distance from the player, if this is a touch controller, you can add it as a child of the camera node, and stay fixed on screen forever (if I guessed it well enough :] )